# javascript alert is not working correctly with if statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, alert

I would like to check if the mark I selected and input value are the same or not, but the alert in js works even though when they are same. Here is my code! Thanks for your support!

**HTML**

```
<select id="mark">
  <option value="o">o</option>
  <option value="x">x</option> 
</select>
<input type="text" name="block%s" id="block" onchange="check()">
```

**JS**

```
var mark = document.getElementById("mark").value;
var block = document.getElementById("block").value;
function check() {
  if (block != mark) { 
    alert ('Your mark is wrong'); 
    return false;
  } else {
    return true; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put these variables inside function, otherwise there values are determined at the beginning and won't change afterwards.

```js
function check(){
var mark=document.getElementById("mark").value;
var block=document.getElementById("block").value;
if( block != mark) { 
   alert ('Your mark is wrong'); 
    return false; 
}
else{
    return true; 
}
}
```

```html
<select id="mark">
<option value="o">o</option>
<option value="x">x</option> 
</select>
<input type="text" name="block%s" id="block" onchange="check()">
```

Comment: Better to save references to the DOM elements once and compare the values (`mark.value` / `block.value`) inside the function, instead of querying the DOM each time

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript code should be like this : *(The block `var` declared after the function)*

```
<script>
  var mark=document.getElementById("mark").value;

  function check() {
    var block = document.getElementById("block").value;
    console.log(mark + '-' + block)
    if (block != mark) { 
      alert ('Your mark is wrong'); 
      return false; 
    } else {
      return true; 
    }
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: Edited by @theAlexandrian and approved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all create the function `check()` .

You can get value of `options` by `selectedIndex` or `selectedValue`

```
var e = document.getElementById("mark");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

after that compare the value of `selectedValue` and `input` text and display appropriate message according to need in alert

Answer (score 0):

The function check should include all variables. Here, Try this:

```
function check(){
var mark=document.getElementById("mark").value;
var block=document.getElementById("block").value;

if(block != mark) { 
   alert ('Your mark is wrong'); 
    return false; 
}
else{
  alert ('Your mark is right');
    return true; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables should be inside function

Try following:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="block%s" id="block" onchange="check(this)">
```

**Javscript**

```
function check(inputBox) {
var markBox = document.getElementById("mark");
var mark = markBox[markBox.selectedIndex].value;
var block = inputBox.value;
  if (block != mark) { 
    alert ('Your mark is wrong'); 
    return false;
  } else {
    return true; 
  }
}
```

> You can also use `onblur` of input box to call `check()` when user leaves the input box.